# Problem on area of curve area of curve between hyperbola $x^2-y^2=9$, $x$-axis and diameter, which passes through point $(5;4)$ from GRE Math Subject

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Find the area of curve between hyperbola $x^2-y^2=9$, $x$-axis and diameter, which passes through point $(5;4)$

**My solution:** The equation of line is $y=\frac{4}{5}x$ and it intersect hyperbola at points $x=\pm 5$. Also hyperbola intersect $x$-axis at point $\pm 3$. Since there two identical shaded figures in first and third quadrant we get:
$$\text{Area}=2\left[ \int\limits_{0}^{3}\dfrac{4}{5}x\ dx+\int\limits_{3}^{5}(\dfrac{4}{5}x-\sqrt{x^2-9})dx\right]=2\left[ \int\limits_{0}^{5}\dfrac{4}{5}xdx-\int\limits_{3}^{5}\sqrt{x^2-9}\ dx\right]=$$$$2(I_1-I_2)$$

It is easy to calculate that $I_1=10$ and $I_2=10-\ln 81\sqrt{3}$

So the total area will be $=2\ln 81\sqrt{3}=9\ln 3$.

But the answer on the book is half of mine, namely $\dfrac{9}{2}\ln 3 $.

Can anyone explain this ambiguity?

Comment: Hint: $\log x^n = n \log x$. How are square roots written as powers?

Comment: I think that your hint is not applicable here. Could you clarify your thought?

Comment: Try writing $81\sqrt{3} = 3^{\frac{9}{2}}$.

Comment: I know it. Please read my post more carefully. Evenrually i am multiplying $2$ with $9/2 \ln 3$

Comment: @Jack, diameter of hyperbola.

Comment: @Jack, I do not know exactly. This problem was given to me by my friend who have already took this exam.

Comment: What is "the equation of line"?

Comment: @Jack, everything is ok. Indeed (0,0) is its centes.

Comment: Silly me. I was thinking about the two foci. Comments deleted.

Comment: Sean Robertson, Did you understand what i was talking about?